# make failure on libuv AF_LINK | R, Cygwin

Tags: r, cygwin, tidyverse, devtools, libuv

While installing packages in R as

```
install.packages('fs')
#the make requirement fails at the libuv_la-bsd-ifaddrs.lo 

$src/unix/pipe.c:249:15: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   if (addrlen >= *size) {
               ^~
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-poll.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-process.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-signal.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-stream.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-tcp.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-thread.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-timer.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-tty.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-udp.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-cygwin.lo
 $ CC       src/unix/libuv_la-bsd-ifaddrs.lo
$ src/unix/bsd-ifaddrs.c: In function 'uv__ifaddr_exclude':
$ src/unix/bsd-ifaddrs.c:45:41: error: 'AF_LINK' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'AF_HYLINK'?
     return (ent->ifa_addr->sa_family != AF_LINK);
                                         ^~~~~~~
                                         AF_HYLINK
$ src/unix/bsd-ifaddrs.c:45:41: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
$ make[1]: *** [Makefile:2258: src/unix/libuv_la-bsd-ifaddrs.lo] Error 1
```

Cygwin setup includes libuv, libuv-devel, libvirt, libvirt-devel

Am i missing something or is there something i need to patch for this?

Answer (score 1):

the `fs` package is embedding a old version of `libuv` (1.18) the current Cygwin shared lib is based on 1.24 .
The error you see was solved by a proper `#ifdef` in later versions.

What I do not understand is why `fs` is embedding `libuv` instead of using the present version.

So you can ping upstream to upgrade or you can replace the current version with latest vesion of libuv embedded and created a customer version of the `fs` source package.